# IBM MQ Callback function call wait until some job is done

Tags: c++, c, ibm-mq

Hi i am using `MQCB` to register a callback function on my queue for reading new data.
I have used `MQGMO` option of `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT`. So call `MQCMIT` at the end of the callback function too.
Immediately i call `MQCTL` and start consumption of messages in the queue, by which my callback function gets called.

My situation here is, i am doing a specific set of tasks in the call back function and i dont want the callback function to be called on next new message which is put in the queue. I want my set of tasks to be finished first.

I am sure there must be a way to do this, but not able to figure out from google or IBM help site.

Can anyone help me out in this. My code base is C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for Options
MQOP_SUSPEND and MQOP_RESUME
in MQCTL
(see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Ffr41300_.htm )

Regards

Comment: Cool thanks. Is this the only definitive way as i read `If you intend to stop consuming messages for a long time, consider closing the queue and reopening it when consumption continues.`? . Also should I commit my read operation from callback before i resume `MQCTL` ?